# How to display calculation results in namedWindow in opencv (c++)

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

I used [this](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/DisplayManyImages) code to display multiple images in the same namedWindow. Now I want to display some of the calculation results (that I have calculated before with image processing functions).

The results should be displayed in the fourth position of the namedWindow, like I show in the red square in the image below:
[image]

Is there any way in opencv that can throw console window in the namedWindow? Can I copy the results from console window in any other way on the named window? Is it possible to create somehow scrolling window with all information and put them on ?

Comment: obtain your results as type `string` and display them as text using `cv2.putText()`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an new Mat with either ones() or zeros() and then using the function putText to insert your text.

Afterwards show the Mat like the rest before